# Is it possible to actually show the changes made by first workflow (to the repo) to second workflow?

Tags: github-actions, workflow, building-github-actions

I've 2 workflows with the names `update_workflow.yml` and `build.yml`. As the name states, `update_workflow.yml` fetches the changes from the upstream repo and rebase my changes on top of it everyday. While the `buidl.yml` builds the build depending on the changes made.

The thing here to note is that, `update_workflow.yml` calls the `build.yml` after the update:

```yaml
update_fork:
    # Here, comes all the git commands that actually updates the repo
build_now:
    needs: update_fork
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build.yml
    secrets: inherit
```

I've used `workflow_call:` in the `build.yml`.

Everything is working fine, but the actual problem that arises is when the `build.yml` is called.
It builds the build for the previous version and not the latest that `update_fork.yml` updated a minute back.
What changes should I need to make to make sure that, the called workflow `build.yml` is actually building the build for the latest freshly fetched update?
And yes, manually running `build.yml` works fine.

One solution that I found is that to call workflow_dispatch by using cURL request that I'm not comfortable with.
Can I make slight changes to the existing repo without actually using cURL?

Edit1:
I cannot follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73702333/github-actions-reuse-outputs-from-other-reusable-workflows) method either as the output given by `update_fork.yml` updates the entire repo with below given commands:

```bash
git checkout main
git rebase upstream/main || git diff
git push -f origin main
echo "Rebase successful!"
```

Edit2:
Yes, I've added `reference` as `main` on both the files.

`Update_fork.yml`:

```yaml
...
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Forked Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: repo/name
          ref: main
          fetch-depth: '0'
      - name: Next step
...
```

`build.yml`:

```yaml
...
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: repo/name
          ref: main
          fetch-depth: '0'
...
```

Comment: Regarding "**the actual problem that arises is when the build.yml is called.
It builds the build for the previous version and not the latest that update_fork.yml updated a minute back.**", the recently updated repo is not checked out by the the build job, right?

Comment: I've used `actions/checkout@v3` in my `build.yml` as the first step

Comment: Please add that step to your question. Verify the latest reference it's being fed to checkout. Isn't the latest one after rebasing by the previous job?

Comment: You mean, using `ref: main` under checkout on the `build.yml` as well as `update_fork.yml`. Right? I've already done that 2 days back, waiting for upstream update to check.